# How VS2010 packs DB files in installer

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0

question:

I am working on,
Visual Studio 2010 Premium,
I know that there is no possibility to add Local Database.
For this reason, database is added through Server Explorer > Add Connections.

And my DB file is saved in:
C:\Program Files\Micrisoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ContactDB.mdf

How it will compile when it is necessary to make installer of application.
If VS compile all in 1 package - source codes and DB files?
What best practices for this when making Installer of App - if database is added through 
Server Explorer > Add Connnections.

With regards!

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know mdf file is added to your project. If it is not added check the mdf file property `Copy to output Directory` .  This needs to be set `Copy Always` to ensure your mdf file is being copied to output folder.

Here is an another approach to deploying an application with database.

[Deploy your Application and Database](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16231/Deploy-your-Application-and-Database)

Also you can use scripts to create your database from scratch while deploying your application. Check this msdn article

[Specify Pre-Deployment or Post-Deployment Scripts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833410.aspx)